# Reading only str objects from a file

Tags: python, random, readfile

So while working on my program I'm trying to read a file, bring back all the information contained. While another function splits the list and random generates a string contained. If it's not a string, try again.

Unfortunally my program flips out while doing this and completely refuses to obey or just gives me an error or yeah, flips out.

So now I'm looking for a way to only read the string objects so I can skip the whole part where it checks if it's an integer or not.

```
import random
from random import randrange
def readfile(file):
    try:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        fil = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return fil
    except IOError:
        print('fil finns inte')
        return None

def chooseword(lista):
    while True:
        lista = random.choice(lista)
        ordet = lista.split()
        x = randrange(len(ordet))
        ord = ordet[x]
        try:
            if ord.isalpha:
                return ord
        except:
            print("none")

print(chooseword(readfile("file.txt")))
```

I've tried with working with random.choice instead of randrange which made no difference.

So, how would I go forward to only import string objects like words, ex: Banan and not 123 or ¤%&.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: The reason your program breaks in that the first time through the `while` loop, you throw out all lines but one; then you no longer have a list of lines to choose from. My advice: Don't personalize your program. It's not flipping out, you are. Understand what python is doing, because it's not going to change; you have to change your understanding, and your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a lot of things wrong in your code. The most glaring issue is in your `chooseword` function. You will have an infinite loop if the first string you read is not an alphabet string because you overwrite `lista` with the value of a random element, so therefore, when you iterate the loop again you'll be reading the same element over and over and never exit the loop.

Checking if the string contains only letters is a function call, so you have to call `.isalpha()`. Also, if you hit a non alpha string, then I suspect you expect to hit the except (say that 5 times fast :)) and print `'none'`...that'll never happen with your code. Just use `if, else` conditionals.

Your fixed code:

```
import random
from random import randrange
_file = file

def readfile(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        try:
            return f.readlines()
        except:
            print('fil finns inte')    # not sure what your trying to catch here

def chooseword(lista):
    while True:
        dont_overwrite_lista = random.choice(lista)
        ordet = dont_overwrite_lista.split()
        x = randrange(len(ordet))
        ord = ordet[x]
        if ord.isalpha():
            return ord
        else:
            print('none')


print(chooseword(readfile("file.txt")))
```

PS

It's rare code "refuses to obey" ;). Remember computers are stupid and do exactly what we tell them to do.

Comment: Haha I know it should obey just fine if I knew more how to code. But I'm a newbie and did not know it overwrote. Explains some and that never ending loop sure rings a bell.

Some of the code is jibberish mostly for me to understand what I've done which will be fixed for the better when the logistics works. 

I will try out your fixed code and hope for the best! Thanks alot